# Colors bounds for streamplot

Tags: python, matplotlib, colorbar

I need to create a streamplot with a colorbar indicating the speed of a given line. The thing is, there's 2 points in my speed data with excessive value, totally rescaling the scale of the colorbar, and I can't really erase them.

I've searched way to prevent it without modifying the data (like with cmin, Vmin, Vmax...), but it seems streamplot doesn't have function for this...

So **is there a way to add limits to the cmap in a streamplot ?**

Comment: Set the values in the normalization to vmin and vmax to exclude the two outlier values, then allow to extend the upper limit similar to what is used in [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71237109/8881141).

Comment: I'm not sure how to use the norm function in streamplot, tried something like norm = [Vmin, Vmax] but not accepted 
(the documentation doesn't give example about it)

Comment: The [streamplot](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.streamplot.html) accepts with `norm` a colormap normalization. In this [normalization process](https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/colors/colormapnorms.html?highlight=normalize), you can define whether you allow to extend beyond the defined vmin/vmax limits. You can even choose a different color for outliers. It looks unnecessarily complicated on paper (why can't I just tell this directly the plot routine?) but allows to easily ensure the same colormap/normalization over a range of different objects.

Comment: Oh okay I got it! It works, thanks :-)

Answer (score 0):

I think this should help.

```
## import matplotlib 
matplotlib as mpl

## Set colormap for the colorbar
cmap = mpl.cm.rainbow

#### Use norm to set you vmax and vmin
norm = mpl.colors.Normalize(vmin=0, vmax=35)

## Pass norm as argument while plotting
strm = ax.streamplot(x=ds["longitude"],y=ds["latitude"], u=ds["u"], v=ds["v"], color=ds.u.values, linewidth=1, cmap='rainbow', density=0.6, norm=norm)

fig.colorbar(strm.lines, label = 'wind speed [m$^2$]', shrink=0.6)
```